# Should one use the Application or HomeController in Scala Play?

Tags: playframework

When activator new is run a controllers folder is created containing:

- AsyncController
- CountController
- HomeController

Various Scala Play examples contain an Application.scala.

Is the HomeController.scala the successor of the Application.scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it was changed in the few last releases.

Long Answer: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5721

> **Purpose**
>
> Changes instances of `Application` to `HomeController` and uses `class
>   HomeController` instead of `object HomeController` to make the code more
>   DI aware.
>
> **Background Context**
>
> The new Play templates use `HomeController` as a name instead of
>   `controllers.Application` to avoid confusion with play.api.Application.
>   Since 2.5.x uses InjectedRoutesGenerator by default, use of `object
>   Application` should be a deprecated usage and there are multiple bugs
>   based on outdated docs.